# GCP, AWS pricing on a a low performance nodejs app

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

The app is a Nodejs-app. Express API which also serves a react-app. Database is MongoDB. I have a few hundred users. Not much CPU at all. Running it on a VPS, costs about 12$ a month. Thinking about moving it to the cloud.

MongoDB atlas costs 9$ a month. what would be the price to get a AWS or GCP solution (tried Azure, was 5 times the price of my VPS) to serve my nodejs app? Lowest possible CPU, memory etc?

Comment: t3a.micro would cost about $12/month depending on bandwidth.

Comment: Actually, it's about half that for linux on demand.  https://www.ec2instances.info/?filter=t3a&cost_duration=monthly&selected=t3a.micro is a great site to view aws costs.  Note that "a" in that name stands for ARM. you can't ship x86 to arm, but as long as you build everything on arm you shouldn't notice a difference